# How to convert Apache Lucene .fdt file to .csv?

Tags: apache, lucene

I'd appreciate advice how to convert .fdt file created by Apache Lucene into some kind of "user friendly" database - ideally .csv, but also .txt or .xlsx or whatever similar would be nice.

I visited lucene.apache.org , but there is no some kind of "viewer" for this file; I downloaded Apache Lucene, but I'm not sure how to proceed - this is not an installation package.

I don't want to learn Lucene, I just need to have the database from this file in a structured way, so I cannot afford to invest time to learn Lucene just for that, I'm not a programmer.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have the rest of the index files as well, you should be able to open it with [Luke](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases).

Comment: @femtoRgon Thanks for comment! I have entire index folder, and I downloaded Luke, but it seems it cannot open this - I get message: Invalid directory at the location, check console for more information. Last exception:
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooOldException: Format version is not supported (resource BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Installation\index\segments_1"))): -11 (needs to be between 1071082519 and 1071082519). This version of Lucene only supports indexes created with release 4.0 and later.

Comment: @strugar you probably downloaded a version of Luke which is not compatible with the version of lucene which was used to create this index. Do you know which lucene version it is?